# Interference term in hadronic processes

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hadron-dynamics

If we consider two hadronic processes with the same final state, [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TANKN.jpg) :

[image: diag1]   [image: diag2]

should one also include an interference term in cross-section despite the different propagators?
What would be in cases like Vector Meson Dominance, when we have additional channel mediated by photon?
Or should we only include interference terms when the mediating particle is the same and only topology is different?

Comment: You add amplitudes, irrespective of the mediating particle, and compute the resulting interference. Isn't that what your book/course says?

Answer (score 0):

In a 1964 Cern Yellow report Veltman teaches how to evaluate Feynman diagrams. [In page 98 of this pdf](http://cds.cern.ch/record/276704/files/CERN-64-13-V-3.pdf)

> " In chapter 2 we  have seen that the matrix element must be squared in order to get to observable quantities"

and goes on to give an example  with two diagrams . So as long as you have correct Feynman diagrams for the same input and output particles , correct meaning conserved quantum numbers taken into account, the $M^*M$ will have interference of the two diagrams by construction .

Those lectures taught me that struggling through a field theory course had as an  objective  calculation of crossections. :)